# Angular ng-repeat output groupBy value

Tags: angularjs

I have this AngularJS repeater where i group my items by a property.

**Data:**

```
items = {
Load: 0,
Unit: 0,
object: {
  Property: "prop"    
}
```

}

**Repeater**

```
<div class="horizontalList">
                <ul ng-repeat="(index, item) in vm.items | groupBy: 'object.Property' | toArray: true">  

                    <div>GET OBJECT PROPERTY HERE</div>  

                    <li ng-repeat="item in item | orderBy:'index'">
                        <div ng-bind="item.Load"></div>
                        <div ng-bind="item.unit"></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

It works fine, except i cannot output the value of **object.Name**, I've tried various things like:

```
<div ng-model="Item.object"></div>
<div ng-model="item.object.Name"></div>
<div ng-model="vm.items[index].object.property"></div>
```

Comment: there isn't Name property inside items object

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this it's easy to understand your issue that way.

Comment: No, i want the name of the object inside the item.

Comment: A codepen would be great. Toarray and groupby are custom filters, correct?

Comment: Edited question, i forgot to state what i needed >.<